# c++ getline function skipping over cin

Tags: c++, getline

Not sure what is going on with my code. The issue is with my getline function. Using the code snippet:

```
string searchItem;
cout << "Enter the name of the item: ";
getline(cin, searchItem);
cout << searchItem << endl;
```

I have put this snippet in a program by itself and it works fine but when I use it in my code it skips right over it as if there is no cin at all. The program does not pause to let the user enter anything. Even taking the below portion of code and putting it in a different program it still does the same thing. I did not want to put the full code since it is a homework assignment.

```
#include <iostream> // used for standard I/O
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>  // used for file I/O
#include <string>   // used for string var
#include <vector>   // used for vectors
#include <iomanip>  // used for setprecision()


using namespace std;

void menu();

int main()
{
    menu();
}

void menu()
{
int mainMenuChoice;

cout << "Choose among the following options." << endl;
cout << "1: To see if an item is in the store." << endl;
cout << "2: To buy an item." << endl;
cout << "3. To check the price of an item." << endl;
cout << "4: To print the inventory." << endl;
cout << "9: To end the program." << endl;
cin >> mainMenuChoice;

cout << endl;
cout << endl;

// To see if an item is in the store.
if (mainMenuChoice == 1)
{
    int i = -1; // inventory location 
    string searchItem;
    cout << "Enter the name of the item: ";
    getline(cin, searchItem);
    cout << searchItem << endl;

    menu();
}
}
```

Comment: Try putting a `cin.get()` after you read into `mainMenuChoice`.

Comment: @JamesRoot that worked, would you mind explaining what the problem there is. I am still learning c++

Comment: The link in my above comment should also explain, but when you hit enter after the number, that character `/n` gets left in the buffer. When the program reaches the `getline`, it sees the remaining newline character and reads just that in.

Comment: @JamesRoot Thank you!!!

Comment: If you have a look at the "Related" questions on the right, you can find at least 4 that deal with this issue, among which the one linked by James Root.